# How do i get a URL from angularJs in php

Tags: php, angularjs, url, parameters

I can not get the current URL of angular in PHP at all, I've already tried using 
$_SERVER ["HTTP_REFERER"], plus it comes the original path of the file...

Original url em angularJS:
http://link.com.br/ead/moodle2017/#/aulas/39

I need the parameter to manipulate in php.

AngularJS:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "pages/home.php"
    })
    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl : "pages/home.php"
    })
    .when("/aulas/:id", {
        templateUrl : "pages/aulas.php"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
})
```

PHP Current Page:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

    include '../../../config.php';
    include '../api/conexaoMysql.php';

    //verifica se aluno é matriculado no curso
    $idcurso = 39;
    $context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, $idcurso);
    var_dump($context);
    //if(!is_enrolled($context, $USER->id) && !user_has_role_assignment($USER->id,1)){  
        //echo '<script>window.location = "home";</script>';
    //}

?>
```

Comment: are you using router? put js code in your question

Comment: I use the angularJS ngRoute.

Comment: where do you want to use current path? which file do you try php codes to get current path?

Comment: On my current pages. aulas/atividades/etc... I'll put the php code above.